# How to make panel not update on button press

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, panel

I have an asp:panel that I fill with images when the page is loaded, and I use JQUERY to add a class to the images, so that when I click a button I can run a method that deletes the pictures from my database.

But I have a problem.  Since I fill the panel with images when the page gets loaded, when I press the button, the panel gets emptied before the button can run its method, so all the classes gets reset.  I can't just put the code that fills the panel in an `if(!IsPostBack)`, since that will just empty the panel when I press the button.

Here's my code for getting images into panel:

```
foreach (DataRow S in method.Get.Images().Rows)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        img.ID = S["fldID"].ToString();
        img.CssClass += "Image";
        img.ImageUrl = "/img/" + S["fldImg"];

        pnl.Controls.Add(img);
    }
```

Here's the code for the button:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control C in pnl.Controls)
    {
        Response.Write((C as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image).CssClass);
        if (C is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = C as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image;
            if (img.CssClass.Contains("selected"))
            {
                Response.Write(img.ImageUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any more of the code just say it and I'll add.

### SOLVED

I found a solution to the problem by using TextBoxes that get values in the JQUERY code and the button uses that info to delete them.

Comment: why dont you use ajax update panel for this case

Comment: You actually ask "how to keep Panel's state" The answer is, you save it some how on viewstate and recreate it on PageInit, or not save it, just recreate it, before the rest take place.

Comment: @Amarnath i dont want the panel to update and the times i've tried to make a update panel around the button with asyncpostback (so it only would be the button that updates) it just does nothing

Comment: @Aristos how would i do that?

Comment: @Jemomi_DK You do it the same way you create it at the first place... I believe your issue is on witch point you need to add your create each time

Comment: @Aristos So do i add something to the panel or what i dont understand

Comment: Can you write there your page load event code?

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz i figured out a way by using textboxes that have display:none; so they excist in the code but not visible on the page :)

Comment: ahahaha. good luck bro :)

Comment: Some tips: don't use Response.Write, as you have no control over where in the DOM the written text will appear. Avoid the UpdatePanel, as you don't have very much control over it and it can lead to headaches. And since you're using jQuery AJAX, it's probably a good idea to not have it postback to the server on button click. Use the AJAX response to send any updated information back to the client.